# Figurative use of "address"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Can the word "address" be used figuratively, to mean a place that people turn to (for help, advice, etc.).

If not – what would be a better word for this connotation?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I'm looking for something that would be applicable here:

> The Wonderland Building Center is the country's main ** address ** for any Wonderlandian seeking advice on building or renovating his or her home.

Comment: I'll try to narrow down my search. "Place" isn't what I'm looking for. I'll give you an example:

The Wonderland Building Center is the country's main  ** address ** for any Wonderlandian seeking advice on building or renovating his or her home.

Comment: Edited your post to include this

Comment: Please see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [place](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/place)?

> A building or area used for a specified purpose or activity:

**EDIT**: In your example, **[destination](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/destination)** should work

> The Wonderland Building Center is the country's main **destination** for any Wonderlandian seeking advice on building or renovating his or her home.

---

And no, I don't think you can use [address](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/address) in that sense